# What is the best way to use for loop in python opencv which saves its outputs(images) in multiple variables?

Tags: python, opencv

I have an function to resize an given image. However, what I want to do is, use an for loop in it, so that, I can resize as many image as I want and save them in different variable.

Here I have is the image reading code from opencv.

```
image1 = cv2.imread(test1.jpg)
image2 = cv2.imread(test2.jpg)
```

And below is the image resizing function. Currently, its takes image1, resize it and then save it to img1. How to use for loop so that I could pass image1, image2, image3 and so on and it get saves into img1, img2, img3..... respectively.

```
def image_resize(image1, width=None, height=None,inter=cv2.INTER_AREA):
    # initialize the dimensions of the image to be resized and
    # grab the image size
    dim = None
    (h, w) = image1.shape[:2]

    # if both the width and height are None, then return the
    # original image
    width is None and height is None:
        return image1

    # check to see if the width is None
    if width is None:
        # calculate the ratio of the height and construct the dimensions
        r = height / float(h)
        dim = (int(w * r), height)

    # otherwise, the height is None
    else:
        # calculate the ratio of the width and construct the dimensions
        r = width / float(w)
        dim = (width, int(h * r))

    # resize the image
    resized = cv2.resize(image1, dim, interpolation = inter)

    # return the resized image
    return resized

img1 = image_resize(image1, height = 500)
```

It may be dumb question to ask. But I am new to this programming zone. So, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it using for loop assuming you have 10 images as an example.

**Explanation:** Create an empty list `resized_images` to store the resized images. Let's assume you have 10 images named as `test1.jpg`, `test2.jpg`, `test3.jpg` and so on. You use an index `i` to iterate over the 10 values and then read the image using `imread` in the for loop and call the function. The return value from the function is now stored in a list called `resized_images` which you can access later. `'test%s.jpg' %i` is the way to dynamically read different images with variable names.

Now once all the images are resized, you can access the first resized image as `resized_images[0]`, second resized image as `resized_images[1]` and so on. The indexing in python starts from 0 hence the first image is accessed using index `[0]`.

```
def image_resize(image, width = None, height = None, inter = cv2.INTER_AREA):
    dim = None
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    if width is None and height is None:
        return image

    if width is None:
        r = height / float(h)
        dim = (int(w * r), height)
    else:
        r = width / float(w)
        dim = (width, int(h * r))

    resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = inter)
    return resized

resized_images = []
number_of_images = 10

for i in range(1, number_of_images+1):
    image = cv2.imread('test%s.jpg' %i)
    img = image_resize(image, height = 500)
    resized_images.append(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a dictionary and defining the image details, which to be passed to function `image_resize` and using loop will help .
Here is sample code

```
def image_resize(image1, width = None, height=None,inter=cv2.INTER_AREA):

# initialize the dimensions of the image to be resized and
        # grab the image size
        dim = None
        (h, w) = image1.shape[:2]

        # if both the width and height are None, then return the
        # original image
        if width is None and height is None:
            return image1

        # check to see if the width is None
        if width is None:
            # calculate the ratio of the height and construct the dimensions
            r = height / float(h)
            dim = (int(w * r), height)

        # otherwise, the height is None
        else:
            # calculate the ratio of the width and construct the dimensions
            r = width / float(w)
            dim = (width, int(h * r))

        # resize the image
        resized = cv2.resize(image1, dim, interpolation = inter)

        # return the resized image
        return resized

resized_images = []
#here image_name is name of the images,
# in image_width/image_height add width/height according to image 

obj = { image: [image_name],
       width :[image_width],
       height:[image_heights],
       inter =cv2.INTER_AREA
       }

def fun(obj):
    for i in obj:
        for j in i:
            img = image_resize(i['image'][j],i['width'][j],i['height'][j],i['inter'])
            resized_image.append(img)

fun(obj)
```